# PostgreSQL trigger function to capture updated field

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

I am querying data from server to update fields in my local DB.

But, I have more than 100 columns hence I just want to know which column has new value(different than previous) so that I can use only those fields to prepare/make/build update command to my local DB.

EXAMPLE: I have 100 columns already in my DB. Same row in server has been update. Now that I have fetched all those 100 columns from server.(*Stored in list object to make prepare statement in Java*). Only 10 from 100 columns have updated. I want to which 10 columns have been updated.

How to do it with triggers?

Or there is any other way than triggers like, in Cassandra, ***inserting*** using same PK will act as an ***update*** for a row.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do the update you can add a RETURN statement for show updated rows.
You cn see more on the documentation of Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html

Comment: Not After update, but before updating values, I want to check which which column values will differ from previous one.

Comment: I'll Edit my question to limit it to triggers